# Calculate IP Range from IP String equal to x.x.x.x/x

Tags: javascript

How could or would I calculate the range of IP given an IP string like `x.x.x.x/x` most common cases could be `198.162.1.1/24` but could be anything, in that anything that's legally allowed.

I want to take `198.162.1.1/24` and convert it to 
198.162.1.1 - 198.162.1.124 or whatever the equivilant would be legitimately. So trying to figure out how to mathematically and dynamically figure that out with javascript.

Comment: `198.162.1.1/24` would be `198.162.1.1` - `198.162.1.255`, right?  `/24` would be a mask of `255.255.255.0`, yes?

Comment: Do you understand at all what each part of the ip address represents? Based on your example, it seems like you don't.

Comment: @JeffMercado admittedly no, your assumption is correct I do not know well enough about how IP Addresses work. But feel free to elaborate further

Answer (score 10):

Baseaddresse of the subnet: IP-address & (and) netmask.

Highest address: baseaddress filled with 1 instead of zero at the positions where netmask is zero.

e.g.: `198.162.1.1/24` =>

base: `198.162.1.1 and 255.255.255.0`

Block 1: `198 and 255 = 198`

Block 2: `162 and 255 = 162`

Block 3: `1 and 255 = 1`

Block 4: `1 and 0 = 0`

=> 198.162.1.0.

high: `198.162.1.0 or 0.0.0.255`

Block 1, 2 and 3 are the same.

Block 4: `255`

=> 198.162.1.255

Now some code (client side js):

```js
function getIpRangeFromAddressAndNetmask(str) {
  var part = str.split("/"); // part[0] = base address, part[1] = netmask
  var ipaddress = part[0].split('.');
  var netmaskblocks = ["0","0","0","0"];
  if(!/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/.test(part[1])) {
    // part[1] has to be between 0 and 32
    netmaskblocks = ("1".repeat(parseInt(part[1], 10)) + "0".repeat(32-parseInt(part[1], 10))).match(/.{1,8}/g);
    netmaskblocks = netmaskblocks.map(function(el) { return parseInt(el, 2); });
  } else {
    // xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    netmaskblocks = part[1].split('.').map(function(el) { return parseInt(el, 10) });
  }
  // invert for creating broadcast address (highest address)
  var invertedNetmaskblocks = netmaskblocks.map(function(el) { return el ^ 255; });
  var baseAddress = ipaddress.map(function(block, idx) { return block & netmaskblocks[idx]; });
  var broadcastaddress = baseAddress.map(function(block, idx) { return block | invertedNetmaskblocks[idx]; });
  return [baseAddress.join('.'), broadcastaddress.join('.')];
}

console.log(getIpRangeFromAddressAndNetmask("192.168.138.0/23"));
console.log(getIpRangeFromAddressAndNetmask("192.168.138.0/255.255.254.0"));
```

working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kLjdLadv/

Validation is missing. you can do it by your own.

Answer (score 6):

Brief overview on that format. An ip address (IPv4) is a 32-bit number. We often view it in the dotted decimal form where each byte of the 32-bit number is shown in decimal form separated by dots.  The address itself can be broken up into two parts, the subnet followed by the address.  The number after the slash indicates how many bits the subnet occupies in the address.

To get the start and end range of addresses, you first need to figure out what the subnet is for the address.  That part does not change and the address can range from 0 to the max remaining bits.

The easiest way to do this is to convert the ip address to the 32-bit number form, create a bitmask representing the subnet and apply the mask to get the address ranges.  The start address, you clear the address bits, the end address, you set the address bits.

```
function u(n) { return n >>> 0; } // we need to treat the numbers as unsigned
function ip(n) {
    return [
        (n >>> 24) & 0xFF,
        (n >>> 16) & 0xFF,
        (n >>>  8) & 0xFF,
        (n >>>  0) & 0xFF
    ].join('.');
}

var addr = '198.162.1.1/24',
    m = addr.match(/\d+/g),       // [ '198', '162', '1', '1', '24' ]
    addr32 = m.slice(0, 4).reduce(function (a, o) {
        return u(+a << 8) + +o;
    }),                           // 0xc6a20101
    mask = u(~0 << (32 - +m[4])); // 0xffffff00
var start = ip(u(addr32 & mask)), // 198.162.1.0
    end = ip(u(addr32 | ~mask));  // 198.162.1.255
```

Comment: This is a _very_ simplified explanation. Refer to a reference to how IP works and the addresses.

Comment: As thanks, here is yours updated to a function: `const u = n => n >>> 0, ip = n =>  [ (n >>> 24) & 0xFF, (n >>> 16) & 0xFF, (n >>>  8) & 0xFF, (n >>>  0) & 0xFF].join('.');
const expandCIDR = (cidr) => {
  let m = cidr.match(/\d+/g), addr32 = m.slice(0, 4).reduce((a, o) => u(+a << 8) + +o), mask = u(~0 << (32 - +m[4]));
  return[ ip(u(addr32 & mask)), ip(u(addr32 | ~mask)) ]
}`

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using something from npm, there's already a library out there that does exactly what you want. First, `npm install netmask`. Then run this code. I'm using node 4.1.1

```
"use strict"

const Netmask = require('netmask').Netmask

let block = new Netmask('198.162.1.1/24')
block.forEach( (ip, long, index) => {
  console.log("Next IP is", ip)
})
```

The output will be the entire range of addresses for that CIDR notation.

Comment: I was facing a similar problem as the OP, but since I'm using Node.js, the Netmask library was indeed helpful. Thank you for your suggestion!